# What is the type of history in typescript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am now passing the `routecomponentprops` history to the helper function.

This is the main component

```
const FinishEmailSignup: React.FunctionComponent<RouteComponentProps> = ({ history }) => {

  useEffect(( ) => {
    testEmailAuth(history);
 }, [history])
```

Now this is the another component where I put all the helper functions.  I am now giving the type `any` to the `history` prop.
What is the correct `type` for the `history` prop

```
export function testEmailAuth ( history: any ) {
    if (firebase.auth().isSignInWithEmailLink(window.location.href)) {
          //Do Something
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can get the type from the 'history' package, which react-router depends on:

```
import { History } from 'history';

export function testEmailAuth(history: History) {
```

Alternatively, you could get to it like this:

```
import { RouteComponentProps } from 'react-router-dom';

export function testEmailAuth(history: RouteComponentProps['history']) {
```

Comment: Thanks, bro for your answer.
IDK y my question got a negative though